# Drop Down Year Showing Last Year Twice

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am working on creating a drop down button that lets one select the year from a list of options in order to sort through a data table. The code (reproduced below) keeps repeating the last year available, I can't seem to figure out why it is doing this. I am using PHP to pull from a MySql database.

```
      <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Select Year</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <?php
         $year = array();

       while($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subject_set)) {
           $i=0;
          $exists = 0;
          $n = count($year);
           while($i < $n){
            if ($subject['year'] == $year[$i]){
              $exists = 1;
            }
            $i++;
          }
          if($exists == 0){
            $year[$n] = $subject['year'];
            echo "<a href=\"index.php?year={$subject['year']}\"> {$subject['year']} </a>";
      }
     }
     $subject_set = find_all_subjects();
      ?>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The provided code seems to work as intended with a sample array instead of a mysqli result set: https://3v4l.org/1ibha

Comment: By the way, the [`in_array()`](https://secure.php.net/in_array) function might be of interest here.